# Slash being escaped in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-plugins, slash

I'm using jquery.history plugin in my web-app and have a problem with '/' being escaped, so for example
I need to have following URL generated

**/SomeAction#Resource/ResOne**

but got

**/SomeAction#Resource%F2ResOne**

for loading the URL I use

$.history.load(btn.attr('action-name'));

where **btn** element has attribute action-name **'Resource/ResOne'** (it has '/' symbol in source code)

So the question is how to achieve that '/' symbol will remain in the URL?
(this approach is used in gmail when you open on some mail from the inbox, so please don't answer with techniques that use decoding techniques on server side)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

decodeURIComponent in itself probably won't help. Look at the plugin, and specifically, let's look at the 'locationWrapper'. This is one of the things that are likely being called when you add 'load' a url.

```
var locationWrapper = {
    put: function(hash, win) {
        (win || window).location.hash = this.encoder(hash);
    },
    get: function(win) {
        var hash = ((win || window).location.hash).replace(/^#/, '');
        try {
            return $.browser.mozilla ? hash : decodeURIComponent(hash);
        }
        catch (error) {
            return hash;
        }
    },
    encoder: encodeURIComponent
};
```

Notice the encoder part? You'll need to override that somehow, or replace the encoder.. from a quick glance at the code, it doesn't look overly 'extend' friendly. So, according to that code, it doesn't matter if you 'decode' the action-name a million times, it's still going to encode it again.

Edit: just found this on the wiki:

```
$.history.init(callback, { unescape: true });
```

It's a configuration option. https://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/wiki/How-to-use-the-forward-slash-instead-of-ugly-%27%252F%27

Anyway, good luck!